# cs0002 Unable to load message string from resources .net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net

working on a c# .net 4.0 application using wpf,  got an error CS0002 (see trace below) when the application on a pc with xp prof sp3. on other machines its runs well (also win xp prof sp3). 
after spending a lot of time on searching for a solution, ive no idea what to do next, and maybee you can help.

i checked the access rights of the c:\windows\temp dir,and temp dir for the TEMP and TMP environment settings, all dirs are fully accessable. the pc has win xp sp 3, and i have installed all updates. i'm running the code as administrator.

if you have any suggestion, let me know !
thanks.

```
Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.
error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources.

   at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration..ctor(SettingsFactory settingsFactory)
   at MyNHibernateSession.OpenSession()
```

Comment: after searching and searching solved the issue by copying the c:\windows\microsoft.net dir from another pc to the pc with this issue. after that, it works....

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem of your .NET install (Type Initialization). Please try to uninstall/reinstall the .NET framework on your machine.

http://comicrack.cyolito.com/forum/8-help/17699-error-on-comicrack-startup